# Customizing the jquery.datatables plugin to filter with a regex on two columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, datatables

I am using the jquery datatables plugin found [here](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html). There are two columns named "New GL" and "Old GL". The datatables plugin has a built in feature called search which filters the data in the table based on the keyword you enter into the textbox.

Here is what my data currently looks like:
[image]

When I type "40.88.1010.0" or "40.88.600000.05" into the textbox I want 
this record to appear.
[image]

The same rule applies to all of the records. I want the search to continue to filter all of columns using one single textbox but for the columns "New GL" and "Old GL"...I want the user to be able to use both "-" and "." characters.

My initial thought would be if the datatables had a regex option it would work because "." in regex is any character. But I only want the rule to apply to those two columns.

Is this possible to do using the datatables plugin?

Here is my current datatable initialization code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#datatable').DataTable({ "iDisplayLength": 50 });
});
```

Comment: For `New GL`: `[-0-9]{15}` that is a digit or a dash exactly 15 times.

Comment: Do you want user to be able to search other columns or just those two?

Comment: @Gyrocode.com I would like the user to be able to search all of the columns.

Comment: Can you please show your DataTables initialization code?

Comment: @Gyrocode.com Sure, I have added the code to my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

You need to implement custom search function as shown below.

The drawback of this method is that content in other columns will also be searched in the same manner, i.e. searched by using either `.` or `-` characters.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#datatable').DataTable({ 
       "pageLength": 50 
    });

    $('.dataTables_filter input', table.table().container())
        .off('.DT')
        .on('keyup.DT cut.DT paste.DT input.DT search.DT', function (e) {
            // If the length is 3 or more characters, or the user pressed ENTER, search
            if(this.value.length > 0){            
                // Escape the expression so we can perform a regex match
                var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(this.value);

                // Add regular expression to match both . and - characters
                val = val.replace(/(\\\-|\\\.)/g, "[\\\.\\\-]");

                // Call the API search function
                table.search(val, true, false).draw();

            } else {
                // Ensure we clear the search if they backspace far enough
                table.search("").draw();
            }    
        });
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zatsbLmu/) for code and demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `data-search` attribute [found here](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html). 
Your rows then would become something like that:

```
<tr>
  <td data-search="40.88.1010.0">40-88-1010-0</td>
  <td data-search="40.88.600000.05">40-88600000-05</td>
</tr>
```

Datatables' filtering by default uses data from all rows.

Comment: @user3788671, but with this solution you won't be able to use `-` to search.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com I didn't test it enough. I thought it worked but it doesn't when i type out the whole number.